# Mongodb mongodump & mongorestore --not equal amount of docs

Tags: mongodb, database-backups

How come when I dump my db (or a specific large collection) I get different number of documents.

On the server I performed:

`db.getCollection('locations').count({})` result is: 6,808,925

dump the db with
`mongodump --db db_cars --gzip --archive > db_cars_dump.gz`

And on my local I do: `mongorestore --gzip --archive=db_cars_dump.gz`
And perform a count: `db.getCollection('locations').count({})` the result is: 6,822,145

Note: the size on the local is greater than the server?!?!
I performed this twice (with the entire db and only the specific locations) and received the same result. Why? and how to correct it (have same number as in server)?

Comment: Try giving the count a query and see if the number is different, perhaps `db.locations.count({_id:{$exists:true}})`

Comment: `db.collection.count` may not give you the exact count of the documents - the value is based upon the meta data. Try using the `db.collection.countDocuments()` to get the exact count.